# Probability of $w<X$ where $X$ is a random variable equals the expectation of the probability of $w<X$ where $X$ is a constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

Why is it, that if $w \sim Exp(\lambda)$ and $X$ is a random variable, then

$$ P(w<X)=E(1-e^{-\lambda X})\text{ ?} $$

I know that if $t$ is a fixed value, then
$$ P(w<t) = \int _0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s}ds = 1-e^{-\lambda t} \text{.}$$

Why is the probability of $w<X$, where $X$ is a variable, the expected value of the probability of $w<X$, where $X$ is a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly false without independence of $X$ and $w$. Take $X=w$ for  a counterexample.

Under independence  this follows by Fubini's Theorem . You are just computing the intergral of $I_{w <X}$ w.r.t. the joint distribution of $w$ and $X$ ( which is  a product measure) and integrating w.r.t. $F_w$ and then w.r.t. $F_X$ gives this result.

Comment: Ah I see, so in this example I would get
$P(w<X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_0^X \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt\right) f(X)dX = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(1-e^{-\lambda X}\right) f(X)da = E(1-e^{-\lambda X})$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But your notations are not correct. $dX$ is not meaningful for a random variable $X$. You are integrating w.r.t. $F_X$.